# Stardog raises ConcurrentModificationException upon reasoned query on graph with SWRL Rules

Tags: swrl, pellet, stardog, concurrentmodificationexception

When trying to execute a query with reasoning in a model, I get this error: `000012: com.complexible.stardog.plan.eval.operator.OperatorException: Uncaught error during query evaluation: ConcurrentModificationException`

Ontology model has 2 SWRL rules and is consistent, as it runs fine in Protege (with built-in pellet reasoner). Model has been imported into a stardog rdf model and the query

```
SELECT ?tse
FROM <urn:test_graph>
{
    ?tse a :TaperedShaftEnd
}
```

fails with the above error message.

By deleting the SWRL rules the query runs fine, but of course the model does no longer represent the desired domain. By translating the SWRL rules into stardog native rules, the error appears again.

Reasoning level is set to DL, as SL would imply too high processing times for the target application.
Changing the sameAs flag in the reasoner options does not change the behavior.
Setting the reasoning level to SL, as advised generally in Stardog documentation **would solve the problem on this simplified model**, but as said would result impractical for the use on the final target application.

May you help me in identifying the root cause and the possible solution?
Did anyone experienced the same issue when dealing with SWRL rules?

Here below the concerned model in turtle format, to easily replicate the issue on a test graph.

Heartful thanks to anyone who may help me with this.

```
@prefix : <http://api.stardog.com/> .
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix stardog: <tag:stardog:api:> .
@prefix test: <urn:test_graph#> .

<http://swrl.stanford.edu/ontologies/3.3/swrla.owl#isRuleEnabled> a owl:AnnotationProperty .

<urn:test> a owl:Ontology .

:hasTorqueTransmissionConnectionWith a owl:ObjectProperty , owl:FunctionalProperty , owl:InverseFunctionalProperty , owl:SymmetricProperty , owl:IrreflexiveProperty .

:CouplingConnection a owl:Class ;
    owl:disjointWith :ShaftEnd .

:ShaftEnd a owl:Class ;
    owl:disjointWith :ShaftEnd .

:LeftCouplingConnection a owl:Class ;
    rdfs:subClassOf :CouplingConnection ;
    owl:disjointWith :RightCouplingConnection .

:RightCouplingConnection a owl:Class ;
    rdfs:subClassOf :CouplingConnection .

:LeftShaftEnd a owl:Class ;
    rdfs:subClassOf :ShaftEnd ;
    owl:disjointWith :RightShaftEnd .

:RightShaftEnd a owl:Class ;
    rdfs:subClassOf :ShaftEnd .

:TaperedCouplingConnection a owl:Class , <tag:stardog:api:rule:SPARQLRule> ;
    rdfs:subClassOf :CouplingConnection ;
    <tag:stardog:api:rule:content> """IF {
   ?tse a :TaperedShaftEnd .
   ?tse :hasTorqueTransmissionConnectionWith ?cc .
   ?cc a :CouplingConnection .
}
THEN {
   ?cc a :TaperedCouplingConnection .
}
""" .

:TaperedShaftEnd a owl:Class , <tag:stardog:api:rule:SPARQLRule> ;
    rdfs:subClassOf :ShaftEnd ;
    <tag:stardog:api:rule:content> """IF {
   ?tcc a :TaperedCouplingConnection .
   ?tcc :hasTorqueTransmissionConnectionWith ?se .
   ?se a :ShaftEnd .
}
THEN {
   ?se a :TaperedShaftEnd .
}
""" .

:lcc1 a :LeftCouplingConnection , owl:NamedIndividual .

:lse2 a :LeftShaftEnd , owl:NamedIndividual .

:rcc2 a :RightCouplingConnection , :TaperedCouplingConnection , owl:NamedIndividual ;
    :hasTorqueTransmissionConnectionWith :lse2 .

:rse1 a :RightShaftEnd , owl:NamedIndividual ;
    :hasTorqueTransmissionConnectionWith :lcc1 .
```

Comment: I'd would report this as a bug on the Stardog mailing list, any exception is never intended. They have a very good and fast support, go for it

Comment: Hi, are you referring to the Stardog community @ https://community.stardog.com/ ? May you please provide a link for the Stardog mailing list you're referring to? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: yes, I would give this a try - the devs will give you support there for sure